# What is the difference between attaching a listener to a button to send form data with AJAX and using a standard HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Namely, what are the differences between these 2 approaches:

1. AJAX

I have some random input fields that are not necessarily in a form container (HTML). In my JS file, I have a listener to a button (not necessarily attached or related to the input fields in any way) that pulls values using jquery and use $.post(url, postParams, callback(...) {...} ); to post the data.

2. HTML

I put all my input fields within the context of a form tag and add a submit input whose action points to the corresponding route (this corresponds to the url in the AJAX/jquery method above).

What's the catch? Is it just that option 1 will submit the form without requiring a page refresh while option 2 will?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, method nr 1 will basically allow you to submit the form without refreshing the entire page.

It's best to combine the two using "progressive enhancement".  That basically means that you start with the most basic approach to make sure that it works across the board, and then you spice things up - those who have the capability will get a better user experience.

Take this for example:

```
<form action="somescript.aspx" method="post" class="ajax">
<label for="something">Something</label>
<input type="text" name="something" id="something" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>
```

This is a pretty basic, standard HTML form which works in all devices and everyone should be able to use it successfully, using assistive technologies and what not.

Then add this simple JS script which "hi-jacks" the default functionality of the form and adds AJAX for those who have JS:

```
<script>
  $('form.ajax').submit(function() {
      var form = $(this);
      $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {
          // Do something with the response
      });
      return false;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: these days, ATs require JS for full accessibility, they are not hindered by it. that aside, an ajax vs form submit has nothing to do with user interaction, so one would not inherently be more accessible than the other. in fact, if you had a "tab gauntlet" at the top, say thanks to a nav menu, then the ajax version will be easier for people using AT to operate.

Comment: +1 Progressive enhancement FTW. And indeed, if you have an advanced AT that supports it, you can benefit from AJAX as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a catch. Of course with an AJAX request you can send extra headers (so the server can recognise it is an AJAX request). Many JavaScript frameworks, like jQuery, always add `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` for this purpose. Also you cannot just post to another domain due to [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Apart from that, it's mostly the same.

A small catch: If JavaScript is disabled, or there is an error (possibly because you use a feature that is not supported in a specific browser) the handler won't work.

A catch for the form, it will always load an entire new page, while with AJAX you can just post the form and show a small response without reloading the page.

I think the best approach it to combine them. Make your form work as a normal HTML form, and add a layer of JavaScript/AJAX that isn't *required* to make it work, but adds a better user experience.

Comment: `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. This is not always set, by the way, but most JavaScript frameworks do add this header when executing an AJAX request. It has *almost* become standard. ;) And you could add other headers yourself, a freedom you don't have when building a simple HTML form. Anyway, it's just a difference, not really a catch. A server side script won't do anything with this header unless you explicitly tell it to.